# Unable to create AWS ClientVPNEndPoint with Powewshell

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell, vpn

I would like to create ClientVPNEndPoint by using Powershell module AWSPowerShell.NetCore version 4.1.385 on Windows 10 Pro.

When I run this :

```
    $serverCertificat = Get-ACMCertificateList | where-object { $_.DomainName -eq "server" } 
    $clientCertificat = Get-ACMCertificateList | where-object { $_.DomainName -eq "client1.domain.tld" } 

    $Authentication = new-object Amazon.EC2.Model.ClientVpnAuthenticationRequest
    $Authentication.Type = Amazon.EC2.ClientVpnAuthenticationType.CertificateAuthentication
    $Authentication.MutualAuthentication = new-object Amazon.EC2.Model.CertificateAuthenticationRequest
    $Authentication.MutualAuthentication.ClientRootCertificateChainArn = $clientCertificat.CertificateArn
    
    New-EC2ClientVpnEndpoint -ClientCidrBlock "10.0.0.0/22" `
                            -ServerCertificateArn $serverCertificat.CertificateArn `
                            -AuthenticationOption @($Authentication) `
                            -DnsServer @("172.31.43.131","172.31.30.194") `
                            -vpcid (Get-EC2VPC).VpcId `
                            -ConnectionLogOptions_Enabled $false
```

... I got following error

```
Amazon.EC2.ClientVpnAuthenticationType.CertificateAuthentication: 
Line |
   8 |  … tion.Type = Amazon.EC2.ClientVpnAuthenticationType.CertificateAuthent …
     |                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | The term 'Amazon.EC2.ClientVpnAuthenticationType.CertificateAuthentication' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
New-EC2ClientVpnEndpoint: 
Line |
  12 |  New-EC2ClientVpnEndpoint -ClientCidrBlock "10.0.0.0/22" `
     |  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | Authentication type is required but is missing in the request
```

Note 1 : Link to PS function documentation : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/powershell/latest/reference/items/New-EC2ClientVpnEndpoint.html

Note 2 : I have checked PS Module dll and more specifically the Amazon.EC2.ClientVpnAuthenticationType without any help

```
using System;
using Amazon.Runtime;

namespace Amazon.EC2
{
    // Token: 0x02000032 RID: 50
    public class ClientVpnAuthenticationType : ConstantClass
    {
        // Token: 0x060005C6 RID: 1478 RVA: 0x00012B61 File Offset: 0x00010D61
        public ClientVpnAuthenticationType(string value) : base(value)
        {
        }

        // Token: 0x060005C7 RID: 1479 RVA: 0x00012B6A File Offset: 0x00010D6A
        public static ClientVpnAuthenticationType FindValue(string value)
        {
            return ConstantClass.FindValue<ClientVpnAuthenticationType>(value);
        }

        // Token: 0x060005C8 RID: 1480 RVA: 0x00012B72 File Offset: 0x00010D72
        public static implicit operator ClientVpnAuthenticationType(string value)
        {
            return ClientVpnAuthenticationType.FindValue(value);
        }

        // Token: 0x040000B5 RID: 181
        public static readonly ClientVpnAuthenticationType CertificateAuthentication = new ClientVpnAuthenticationType("certificate-authentication");

        // Token: 0x040000B6 RID: 182
        public static readonly ClientVpnAuthenticationType DirectoryServiceAuthentication = new ClientVpnAuthenticationType("directory-service-authentication");

        // Token: 0x040000B7 RID: 183
        public static readonly ClientVpnAuthenticationType FederatedAuthentication = new ClientVpnAuthenticationType("federated-authentication");
    }
}
```

Comment: You are missing option -ServerCertificateArn.  See : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/powershell/latest/reference/items/New-EC2ClientVpnEndpoint.html  Also https://docs.aws.amazon.com/acm/latest/userguide/acm-overview.html

Comment: What do you mean ? ServerCertificateArn parameter is the second one when I invoke function New-EC2ClientVpnEndpoint...

Comment: You are right.  What version of Net is being used.  Looks like you may have older version of Net.  In version 4.5 your type is defined as a static method.  See : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/EC2/TClientVpnAuthenticationType.html